# Spring Boot 3 Unit Test cannot convert Duration value when ContextConfiguration is used to provide test scope

Tags: spring-boot-test, duration, spring-boot-3, configurationproperties, context-configuration

TL/DR -> Does anyone know how to enable the automatic `ApplicationConversionService` in a Junit test that also specifies a `ContextConfiguration` to only spin up one `ConfigurationProperties` class that has a `java.time.Duration` property?

While testing, I only want to stand up enough Application context to be able to test my `@ConfigurationProperties` class.
To do so, I'm using `ContextConfiguration` to specify the class I want to be used.
My properties class works just fine when everything is a `String`, but the second I add a property that is `java.time.Duration` the **Only** unit tests start to fail.\

From the research I've done, it appears to be an issue with the `ApplicationConversionService` not being registered.
While using *only* `@SpringBootTest` does work, it also requires starting up the entire application context and all properties and configurations.

in a basic spring boot application from `start.spring.io` here are the classes I used to reproduce this
`kotlin 1.8.22`
`spring-boot 3.2.2`

`application.yml`

```yaml
test:
  something:
    expiration: PT3H45M
```

Configuration Properties Class

```kotlin
package com.example.demo.configuration.properties

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import java.time.Duration

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.something")
data class SomethingProps(
    val expiration: Duration
)
```

Configuration Properties Test

```kotlin
package com.example.demo.configuration.properties

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import java.time.Duration

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = [SomethingProps::class])
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [SomethingProps::class])
@SpringBootTest
class SomethingPropsTest(
    @Autowired private val somethingProps: SomethingProps
) {
    @Test
    fun `confirm that something properties function correctly`() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(
            Duration.parse("PT3H45M"),
            somethingProps.expiration,
        )
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.time.Duration' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```